# gcc constexpr intepreted as inline?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this very simple code:

```
 constexpr int main()
 {
    return 0;
}
```

I understand from C++11 standard N3485 that it is illegal:

> The function main shall not be used within a program. The linkage (3.5) of main is implementation-defined.
>   **A program that defines main as** deleted or that declares main to be inline, static, or **constexpr is illformed.**
>   The name main is not otherwise reserved.

When I run it using gcc 4.7.2. it outputs the following error:

```
prog.cpp:1:20: error: cannot declare ‘::main’ to be inline
```

Meanwhile, if I remove the `return 0` from the function body, it reports the same error without even giving a warning about missing return statement from `main`.

Is this a bug of gcc 4.7.2? Why `constexpr` is reported as `inline`? Does the second phenomenon mean that it is OK to not put return statement in `main` or is it by default `return 0` even I do not put return statement into it (I know this is bad practice)?

Thank you.

Comment: In C++ (and now in C too) if there is no `return` in `main` it's implied to be the same as `return 0;`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you. I will remember this fact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`main()` is the only value-returning function which is allowed to have the `return` statement omitted. Flowing off the end of `main()` without returning anything is equivalent to returning `0` (while for other functions it is undefined behavior, see 6.6.3/2).

Per paragraph 3.6.1/5 of the C++11 Standard:

> A `return` statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the `main` function (destroying any objects with automatic
>   storage duration) and calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end
>   of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Concerning the `inline` message, `constexpr` functions are implicitly `inline`. Per paragraph 7.1.5/2 of the C++11 Standard ([courtesy of Luc Danton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719234/gcc-constexpr-intepreted-as-inline/16719290?noredirect=1#comment24071345_16719290)):

> [...]. `constexpr` functions and `constexpr` constructors are implicitly
>   `inline` (7.1.2).

Comment: @LucDanton Ah, that explains why it emits the error message as inline, thank you very much!